# How to Enable Root Login on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: root

Can anyone please guide me on how to enable root login in Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: What kind of login? In GUI?

Comment: Yes from GUI, Like Other User Login

Comment: Not a good thing to do, any way we posted two link for you, check them out ;)

Comment: In 17.04 the directories and files are different i have below files which file do i need to edit ?                                                                                                                                       -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2757 Apr 11  2016 lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  452 Apr  5 04:04 users.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 12 08:45 lightdm.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 12 08:45 lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d